# Android video gallery with dynamic thumbnails

Tags: android, video-processing

I have a samsung tablet running Android 4.2.2. It has a embedded app called "Video Player" which can display dynamic video thumbnails in a Thumbnails GridView Activity. In this activity, you can see a set of looping frames of each video lasting for about 10 secs. Does anyone know how to implement this function? Any clues or inspritions? Thanks.